# Как менять слайды при нажатии на пробел swipeer slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper

Как менять слайды при нажатии на пробел?

```js
let mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'fraction',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
});
```

```html
<div class="dating--user_img dating__img">
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      @forelse($images as $image)
      <div class="swiper-slide dating__slide is-verified" data-verif-text="Фото проверено">
        <img alt="avatar" src="/storage/{{$image->path.$image->image}}">
      </div>
      @empty
      <div class="swiper-slide dating__slide not--user">
        <div class="no--user__search">
          <p class="description">По данным критериям ничего на найдено!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      @endforelse
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, вероятно

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) { 
        document.querySelector('.swiper-button-next').trigger('click'); // .click();
    }
}
```